# Creating a horizontal Scatter line in Dash Graph

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to create horizontal lines from a DataFrame. 
my DF has a timestamp index, and a column called support. for each row in `iterrows()`: I want to create a straight horizontal line from the `timestamp(x)` and the support `column(y)` to `datetime.now()` (x) and same support column (y).

I thought I could do something like this:

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

support_lines = []
for index, row in candles_df.iterrows():
    support_lines.append(go.Scatter(x=candles_df['timestamp'], y=row['support'], mode='lines', name='support'))
```

But `y` requires to be a tuple, or list of some sort. I was thinking this would create points for every timeframe (x) and use the same value for (y)

This creates a single line that isn't horizontal:

```py
resistance_lines = go.Scatter(x=candles_df['timestamp'], y=candles_df['resistance'], mode='lines', name='resistance')
```

which isn't quite what I'm after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured something out. Basically, I created a new DataFrame that has all of the datetimeindex values that the main one has, and added the unique "y" value to every row. Then passed that in to a Scatter plot.

```py
    #Null Check
    if len(candles_df['resistance']) > 0:
        #Getting a unique value for y axis
        for item in np.nditer(candles_df['resistance'].unique()):
            #Add all rows to new DataFrame
            temp_df = pd.DataFrame(candles_df['timestamp'])
            #adding a column with a single value for every row
            temp_df['resistance'] = item
            #create the line 
            data.append(go.Scatter(x=temp_df['timestamp'],
                                   y=temp_df['resistance'],
                                   mode='lines',
                                   showlegend=False,
                                   name='resistance'))
```